# How to make (String,Int) from (String,())?

Tags: haskell, monads

For an exercise on WriterMonads I need to make a function that logs what it does. I mustn't use the tuple constructor (,).

I have an log function already with the result type (String,())
Now I need to use this one but with the result type (String,Int)

But i don't get how to make a (String,()) tuple to (String,Int)

```
logMsg :: String -> (String,())
logMsg  msg = (msg,()) -- Durch Lösung ersetzen.

logOp :: Int -> Int -> Int -> String -> (String,())
logOp v1 v2 res math = do
    logMsg "The value of "
    logMsg $ show v1
    logMsg  math
    logMsg $ show v2
    logMsg " is "
    logMsg $ show res
    logMsg ".\n"


mult :: Int -> Int -> (String,Int)
mult m1 m2 = logOp m1 m2 (m1*m2) "*"
```

I tested that

```
logOp m1 m2 (m1*m2) "*"
```

does the right result of type (String,())

I have no idea, any hints?

Comment: Note that the expression `if a == c then (a,d):r else (a,b):updRel r c d` implicit that `d` and `b` must be same type.

Comment: Oh okay. so that won't work. How else can I change the value of the tuple without the tuple constructor (,)

Comment: Yes, for the edited question, the type of `mult` function should be `mult :: Int -> Int -> (String,())` not `(String, Int)`. What does the `Int` value you want put to second element of the tuple?

Comment: The type is given and can't be changed. The second parameter is the result of the mulitplikation. Can't say why, it just needs to be there.

Comment: Okay, the variable in Haskell is immutable, you can't change it. The only way to construct a `(String, Int)` pair, you have to create an new one.

Comment: Which `Int` is `mult` supposed to include in its return value?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when dealing with monads, one uses the monadic functions `return` and `(>>=)`. You are already using `(>>=)` implicitly in your `do` block.

For `mult`, you can try using a `do` and use `return` inside that. In this very specific case, you can assume that `return` is defined as

```
return :: Int -> (String, Int)
return x = ("", x)
```

(In the general case, it's polymorphic: `return :: a -> (String, a)`)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a method that directly updates the values in a tuple without using the constructor, so I had to write it in an inefficient way. But this one does not use the tuple constructor:

```
mult m1 m2 = head $ zip [fst $ logOp m1 m2 (m1*m2) "*"] [m1*m2]
```

So the `zip` function creates list of tuples out of two lists and then using the `head` function we extract the first element as a tuple and the `fst` function extracts the String from (String,()) pair.